# How to get values from different child in firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Here is my Database architecture where Jobs is the main child and under that there will be users child, and an user can post multiple time. now i want to get all the posts done by all the users at once. is it possible to do that?**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT3MO.jpg

```
setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Jobs")
```

Used that query to get all of the posts from all of the users but didnt work. any better solution for this problem?

```
setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Jobs").child("Uid");
```

this one works but cant use this one because i want to set free for all users to read data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Jobs");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
         String key = ds.getKey();
     for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: ds.getChildren()) {
           // get the child attribute under the random key
        }
    }
 }
 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       throw databaseError.toException();
    }
 });
```

Since you have a reference to node `Jobs` then in the first iteration you can get the random keys (highlighted in your image), and in the second iteration you can get the attributes inside those keys.